# Is a war likely between the U.S. and China?

Tags: united-states, armed-conflict, china

China's economy has grown significantly over the past 20 years. Most forecasters see a time in the near future [where China is the world's largest economy](http://www.usnews.com/news/articles/2015-12-28/americas-days-are-numbered-as-the-worlds-top-economy) and according to some measures [China has a larger economy than the U.S. now](http://www.usnews.com/news/articles/2015-12-28/americas-days-are-numbered-as-the-worlds-top-economyt)! In the past, when a country was threatened with losing its international position, this led to a war (e.g Germany fought Russia in WWI and the reverse in WWII). Similarly, sometimes rising powers will fight to secure their position and change the system, as Japan did when rising vis-a-vis the U.S. There are even signs that such a conflict may be in the offing.

Assuming that China's growth continues, [which is by no means assured](http://www.bloomberg.com/news/articles/2016-01-29/china-stumbles-in-race-to-pass-u-s-as-world-s-biggest-economy), how do political scholars and analysts estimate the likeliness that China and the U.S. will fight a shooting war (i.e. U.S. and Chinese forces will deliberately exchange fire resulting in casualties)?

Comment: Before flagging this question or voting to close it, please see the Meta-question which this question is written to answer. http://meta.politics.stackexchange.com/questions/2665/what-questions-about-the-future-can-we-answer-and-how-should-they-be-answered

Comment: The current answers approach the question of whether China will be the aggressor, but not about whether the U.S. will be the aggressor. Perhaps once the economical dominance of the U.S. becomes to fall, the U.S. will use it's military might to set China back and stay on top.

Comment: @Luke Not necessarily. In fact, Mearsheimer assumes that the U.S. will be the aggressor, and even advocates for it. In the end, especially in the case of the U.S. and China, "it takes two to tango" and only when both countries are willing to fight will it happen. Unless China invades Guam, or the U.S. drops the Marines off in Shanghai, there really isn't a location where one couldn't back down. Some of the discussion assumes that the U.S. is the stronger, and that may give the impression China is the aggressor, but it isn't implied by any of the theories.

Comment: China has [1.3 trillion reasons](https://www.google.com/search?q=how+much+does+the+us+owe+china&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8) *not* to start a war. However, Americans don't ever seem to need a real reason to start one. O.o

Comment: this question has no answer.  But sure: open wide the floodgates to wild speculation and opinion based responses!

Comment: I know you've thought out whether this kind of question should exist, and I applaud you for that, but I disagree with your conclusion. This remains primarily opinion-based. Expert answers are *still* opinions. We cannot answer until it has already happened. This SE is for facts, and questions like this just invite debate, which is not what we're here for.

Comment: I saw this and thought we were on Quora for a second..

Comment: @PointlessSpike Please repost that comment as an answer on the meta-question linked in the first comment.

Comment: @Philipp- Done. I feel like as an answer it should be more substantive, but it really is that simple.

Comment: Given @Philipp's edit, I'm voting to re-open.  It's no longer asking for *an* opinion, but instead the concrete and answerable "What do experts say?"  But as originally written, I'd also have voted to close it.

Comment: [**The war drums are beating**](http://www.ibtimes.com/world-war-3-russia-sends-missiles-counter-nato-plans-historic-military-baltic-buildup-2437257). While the American population is obsessing over which puppet becomes their next "president" or who gets killed in "The Walking Dead", the world has gotten [**closer to nuclear armageddon than it has ever been since the Cuba missile crisis**](http://www.cfr.org/diplomacy-and-statecraft/state-us-russia-relations/p38418)!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The rise of China is a much discussed question among scholars, with those who directly approach the question breaking down into three groups: those who believe conflict is inevitable, those who believe that China and the U.S. can trade places atop the security ladder, and those who believe that trade makes conflict unlikely, meaning that China and the U.S. relative power is immaterial.

The scholar most directly predicting Sino-American conflict is [John Mearsheimer](http://nationalinterest.org/commentary/can-china-rise-peacefully-10204). He contends that as countries approach regional hegemony (i.e. they are more powerful than any coalition in their region) they become free to operate abroad in other regions. The U.S. has been in this position since at least the earliest 20th century when Britain totally withdrew from Canada. He argues that China is in or close to that position now, and that the U.S., recognizing this,

On of Mearsheimer's students, Robert Pape, [argues that China and the U.S. have a relationship much more like that of the U.S. and the U.K.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PYe9fMJk2fo) in the 19th Century, which means that conflict is less likely. Of course, the U.S. and China have a shared interest in stability, but more importantly, the nuclear balance is stable. Because of the shared interests and the stable nuclear balance, conflict is unlikely. Interestingly, Graham Allison used to believe that conflict was less likely, but has [recently sounded an alarm as to the probability of war with China](http://www.theatlantic.com/international/archive/2015/09/united-states-china-war-thucydides-trap/406756/).

Finally, those who espouse the *Capitalist Peace* like [Erik Gartzke](http://erikgartzke.com/) contend that as trade increases the risk of war decreases. This is a more sophisticate version of the "[McDonald's Theory of Peace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Lexus_and_the_Olive_Tree)" or the "[Dell Theory of Peace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_World_Is_Flat)." Since China and the U.S. are major trading partners, war between the two are unlikely. [Patrick McDonald](http://liberalarts.utexas.edu/government/faculty/profile.php?id=pjm438) has directly challenged this argument, however, stating that the phenomenon of peace between trading partners is primarily a function of the fact that the largest trading partners in the past have also been allies of the U.S., meaning that what is being captured is military power, not trade.

For additional information you can see:

- John Mearsheimer, The Tragedy of Great Power Politics, 2nd edition (New York, NY: W.W. Norton, 2014), chapter 10;
- Thomas J. Christensen, “Posing Problems without Catching up: China's Rise and Challenges for U.S. Security Policy,” International Security, Vol. 25, No. 4 (2001), pp. 5-40
- Avery Goldstein, “First Things First: The Pressing Danger of Crisis Instability in U.S.-China Relations,” International Security, Vol. 37, No. 4 (2013), pp. 49-89.

Comment: This is better than other answers but omits some important variables, such as **denial** of hegemony (and not just the drive for one), China's island strategy, etc...

Comment: @4012 I have no idea what 'denial of hegemony' means.

Comment: US isn't as interested in hegemony in the area, nearly as much as in ensuring no hegemon to challenge it emerges (of course the former is preferable, being a stronger outcome including the latter). But certain things differ under the two assumptions, e.g. US can let certain things slide that retain China as non-hegemon despite lowering US's status as hegemon under the denial approach, whereas same things would lead to open conflict under pure hegemon approach.

Comment: ... for example, merely having a firm coalition checking China where US plays second fiddle is sufficient to the denial strategy.

Comment: @user4012 I see. That is usually called an "Off-shore balancing" strategy. So basically, that is what Pape and Mearsheimer are arguing for. The problem with OSB, is that it does nothing to actually check the growth of China. Therefore the question is held in abeyance as to whether or not a conflict will occur. Consequently, both Pape and Mearsheimer can advocate for exactly the same strategy, and believe that the opposite outcome will occur, because Mearsheimer thinks that eventually the U.S. or an ally will start a fight to prevent China from acheiving hegemony, and Pape thinks they won't.

Comment: "Since China and the U.S. are major trading partners, war between the two are unlikely."  IIRC wasn't France's largest trading partner during the non-war periods of the early 20th century Germany?

Comment: "and that the U.S., recognizing this," This appears to be cut off. You might wanna finish the paragraph.

Answer (score 6):

In purely military terms the PRC is presently incapable of projecting power like the USA.  It will be many decades and serious and expensive reforms later before they are able to match American power.  The Chinese military is huge, and certainly was a game changer in the Korean War, but outside of its immediate neighbours connected by land, it does not have the logistics to be able to project force.  Especially not across the Pacific.  Not only in terms of technology and power projection is China lagging behind the US, but simply in terms of its military institutions lacking learned experience, and also lacking an emphasis on independent thinking within their officer corps.

It's important to also be aware of the gulf between contemporary American and Chinese hardware.  American stealth fighters engage in BVR (beyond visual range) combat, and so will fire missiles at their Chinese foes well before they can see them, which is last I recall not something the Chinese or Russians are doing now.  American submarines and destroyers are also far more advanced and numerous than their Chinese counterparts, and what modern equipment China does have in terms of say, armoured vehicles, is mostly outdated; and even their best equipment is still poor compared to western hardware.

The Americans also are not alone, and many of their regional allies would rally to them against the PRC.  Namely Taiwan, Japan, South Korea, Australia, the Philippines.  Let's also not forget that China's aggressive posturing has upset its neighbours, so it would be far more likely that communist Vietnam would, ironically, side with the Americans.  Even India would probably be more likely to side with America than China.

The short of it is simple: the PRC cannot win a war with America.  Now, or in decades to come, without radical change.  The Chinese know that, so they will make grand gestures, but be unlikely to substantiate them for a long time.

I'm assuming that China would not willingly get involved in a war it knows it couldn't win.  That would require an exceptionally dire situation on their part to want to provoke such a war.  And though their leadership is nationalist and authoritarian, they are not stupid.  Therefore, a war between them is unlikely because it would be a disaster.  Especially since they are both nuclear powers, and that on its own will be a substantial deterrent to direct conflict.

Comment: So, it's a little unfair to comment on this, as I posted both the answer and the question as an example for a meta-discussion, but I like where you are going. This is not, however, an answer to this question. Whether or not China could *defeat* the U.S. in a war is immaterial to whether or not it would happen. U.S. and Chinese militaries are already encountering one another in the SCS, so that hurdle is already overcome. Finally, I like your comparison of capabilities, but you have no citations, so we are taking your word for it.

Comment: If I may suggest asking and answering a similar question, focusing on outcome. You will find the majority of the information you need in http://www.mitpressjournals.org/doi/pdf/10.1162/ISEC_a_00225 which is not behind a paywall right now. I think your assessment is right, but it isn't a great answer right now.

Comment: Didn't even notice you answered your own question, I just liked the detail you went into and citations!  I would counter just by saying that people only get into fights they think they can win, at least; the opposite case is surely an outlier.  China would have to be in dire straights to want to get into a war with the US it knew it had no hope of winning.  But you're right, I need some citations.

Comment: So this doesn't belong in the answer, because it is personal and unverifiable here, but I visit China and talk to military fairly frequently, and many of them *believe they can win a war against the US*. This is alarming, because it is A) almost assuredly wrong, and B) represents an aggressive mindset in the Chinese military. Also, while everyone thinks they can win the war they start, they are not always right about that.

Comment: @inappropriateCode Why do you assume that China will be the aggressor in this scenario? I could imagine several scenarios where the US starts the war. For example a WW2-like scenario where China starts invading weaker allies of the US hoping the US will stay neutral but they don't.

Comment: @ThePompitousofLove I'm not sure that's a distinctly Chinese thing.  I recall something said of British generals, whenever they're brought in to talk to the cabinet.  The answer is always yes sir, of course they can do it.  Your comment reminds me of something according to Viktor Suvorov's writings, during the 60s junior Soviet officers were convinced they could win against NATO.  However... mid ranked officers were sure they'd lose.  I presume you're chatting with more junior officers than senior?  Or do you notice it throughout the establishment?

Comment: @Philipp I don't assume the Chinese start things. The fact that the Chinese believe that they could win is germane, however, because that means they are unlikely to back down, when confronted. This is most important in the SCS, where there have already been confrontations with 3rd parties, as you describe. The U.S. might actually start a conflict because China refuses to back down, because China thinks it can win, and the U.S. thinks it can win. At that point, it doesn't matter who is right.

Comment: @innappropriateCode No, it is not a uniquely Chinese thing. Witness the assessments of how the occupation of Iraq would go. Shinseki was right, but he was expelled and there were plenty of other generals willing to say they believed an occupation would be easy, whether they believed it or not.

Comment: @ThePompitousofLove That's a good point, but it shifts the focus to that of psychology, and the feeling of China's elite and their objectives.  In which case both of our answers are missing the point.  Economic and military reality is incidental: what are China's elite thinking?  And how might this differ, from, say, Russia's?

Comment: @inappropriateCode Yes. The person we should be looking at, in that case, is [Jervis](http://press.princeton.edu/titles/1257.html). The only problem with Jervis is that his assertions are not country specific. In other words, he would, and does, contend that the probability of war between two countries is indeterminate, because it frequently relies upon misperception among decision makers. That could be another question, though. :-)

Comment: If one of the key issues preventing China from declaring on the US is the logistics of moving troops and supplies across the Pacific, doesn't that mean they'd be better off in a defensive war? And with the US experiences in Iraq, Korea, and Vietnam, I can't imagine it would be very productive on that end, so similar reasoning applies for why the US wouldn't invade China.

Comment: @ThePompitousofLove: _"I visit China and talk to military fairly frequently, and many of them believe they can win a war against the US. This is alarming, because it [..] B) represents an aggressive mindset in the Chinese military. "_ Because this is in no way the mindset of the Americans.....

Answer (score -2):

Apologies for the lack of references - I have no rep so they wont let me post more than 2 links

Highly likely based on the [image: US Navy Vessels Chart]

What is interesting is what is missing.  The US is rapidly increasing it's littoral combat capability (Shallow water, river systems, island hopping). According to the chart in April 2015 they had 4.  The plan was to move to 55 but it has currently been cut to 40.

To give an idea of how many that is look for the line of Los Angeles class subs in the middle.  It will be about that many.

And they are building these rapidly - they are up to 24 already - not on the chart yet. (Wikipedia: Littoral Combat Ship)

So why littoral ships.

Think pacific war all over again.  Look at the South China sea area map and look for names like Palawan, Spratly Islands and a shiver goes down the spine of US navy planners.  They have fought over that map before.

Add to that Japan has changed its interpretation of its constitution to allow more aggressive actions (Google japan-parliament-passes-change-to-pacifist-constitution)

Add to that US marine corp "pivot" from Okinawa to Darwin Australia. A little less "in your face" and avoids another Philippines while being close enough to be relevant. (Google us-marines-arrive-darwin-us-pivot-amid-concern-tensions-china)

**Diplomacy is what you fill the airwaves with while you muster your forces.**

So either we back down and gracefully let China control that zone or we man up and impose our will.   The graceful approach may make sense from a purely Anglo Saxon view.  The problem is we are also talking about all the Asean nations. Malaysia Vietnam Indonesia etc etc. Lots of countries who don't necessarily want to be under Chinese rule.

Comment: I'm sorry, but your answer is not really on-topic. You are describing US military capabilities and hypothetical strategies for a sino-american war, but do not address in any way how likely that scenario is actually to happen. And then you close with a personal opinion about what the US *should* do, but not backed by any scholary sources.

Comment: my read was the OP was asking about whether it was likely. And I am stating that it is very likely given the massive expense and build up of the equipment needed to fight a war.  Diplomatic words are cheap - but when governments start building weapons suited to a particular theater - which are a real cost from their economy - then war is very close.